# Looking to integrate echosign or docusign with our zoho crm

Tags: docusignapi, echosign

I am looking to integrate echosign or docusign with our zoho crm. So that the information that is put into the contract is transfered into our crm. We currently use Zoho CRM is there anyone that knows if this is possible? If so where could i find anyone that could do this since i do not know anything about programming?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

**DocuSign can be integrated with any language / platform that can make RESTful HTTP requests**.  Furthermore, DocuSign has major advantages over EchoSign, such as the more features (ones that actually matter), more flexibility, a MUCH bigger network (48 Million unique users), and is available in 188 countries and 43 languages.  Perhaps even more important,  on average the DocuSign service has been available 99.99% for the last 5 years, EchoSign has had major publicly known outages.

So yes, you can definitely integrate with Zoho CRM and some people have probably already written custom integrations that do this.  The normal path to take is to simply write your own integration using the [DocuSign REST API](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center)

Also, doing a web search seems to yield several companies that can specifically integrate DocuSign + Zoho CRM for you if you are not a programmer.  If you / your company is not going to be coding it yourself then check out these:

[CloudWork](https://cloudwork.com/integrations/docusign/zoho-crm)

[Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/docusign/zoho-crm/)

And you could always use E-Lance and sites like that as well.

Answer (score 6):

It's absolutely possible with DocuSign.  To achieve this integration, you'd do the following:

- Collect data from signers during their DocuSign signing sessions
  using "DocuSign tabs" (i.e., DocuSign-specific form elements that the
  sender places on the document representing text boxes, checkboxes,
  dropdown-lists, etc.)
- Build a "listener" application and configure **DocuSign Connect** to send XML messages to your listener application when an Envelope is completed.
- Design/build your listener application to receive and process the DocuSign Connect messages -- in your case, "processing the DocuSign Connect messages" would mean reading the "DocuSign tabs" data in each XML message and then using the Zoho CRM API to update records in Zoho with data from the DocuSign tabs. (Note: You can also configure DocuSign Connect to include the completed documents themselves in each message -- doing so would allow your listener application to also store the completed document(s) in Zoho.)

Answer (score 5):

You are right to check with the developer community before investing into any platform. The short answer is DocuSign API is your best choice.  Aligning yourself with a dominant API provider will ensure that:

1. you can find developers easier
2. the bugs have been discovered by someone before you and fixed
3. that the platform has all of the comprehensive features and you will never be stuck.

DocuSign discussions dominate StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=docusign (over 300 and most are answered) and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=echosign (45 and half are not answered).

Elance has double the freelancers that work with DocuSign vs EchoSign.

With DocuSign DevCenter (which was named as #1 by ProgrammableWeb eSignature API report http://blog.programmableweb.com/wp-content/esignature-api-report1.pdf) you have PHP samples for 9 most common scenarios meaning that your developer can get up and going with the integration a lot faster.  There are also 5 other languages there for whatever comes up.

DocuSign also have an interactive API tool iodocs.docusign.com which will allow you to debug your integration simpler.

In closing DocuSign is integrated with hundreds of applications and actually quite a few of those had to redo their integration because they picked another eSignature provider first and hit reliability issues or feature gaps.  Do not make the same mistake.

Here is an incomplete list of publicly available software that integrates with DocuSign: http://www.docusign.com/partners/solution-showcase

Let us know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

I have integrated Zoho CRM / Zoho Creator with DocuSign before.  Here's what the integration looks like:

1. Creator form looks up record from CRM
2. Creator form populates form fields with CRM record data
3. Creator form validate script uses DocuSign API to fill out DocuSign template with form data and send the envelope
4. DocuSign sends response back
5. Creator parses response to see if the action was successful

Contact me if you need help.  This isn't super easy to set up but I've done it before.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating EchoSign with ZohoCRM is absolutely possible. EchoSign has a complete set of APIs that can be used for integration. We use our own APIs to build our integrations with other systems such as Salesforce.com, Microsoft Dynamics, etc. These APIs have also be used by multiple customers to build integrations into their internal systems. We know for a fact that the APIs are sufficient to build integrations into external systems.

You can get information about the EchoSign API at https://www.echosign.adobe.com/en/products/echosign-api-dev-center.html. Additionally if you have any questions please send email to api at echosign.com and we will be able to help you with your integration.

Thanks
Mangesh